# Limit of $1+ \frac13 + \frac15 + ... + \frac{1}{2n+1} -2 \ln n $

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I find this limit:
Limit of $1+ \frac13 + \frac15 + ... + \frac{1}{2n+1} - 2 \ln n $

I apologise for editing my question so many times.

Comment: Should that $\frac 12 \ln n$?

Comment: probably ;) how can I do it with $ \frac12$ ?

Comment: Also the notation is ambiguous, what's the last summand if $n$ is even?

Comment: I've made some changes to my question. Can you please check it out?

Comment: The term $\frac1{2^n+1}$ should most probably be $\frac1{2n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1+ {1 \over 3} + {1 \over 5} + \cdots
     + {1 \over 2n + 1} - 2\ln\pars{n}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &1+ {1 \over 3} + {1 \over 5} + \cdots + {1 \over 2n + 1} - 2\ln\pars{n}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over 2k + 1} - 2\ln\pars{n}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{{1 \over k + 1/2} - {1 \over k + 1}}
> + \half\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k + 1} -\ln\pars{n}}
> - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{n}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \underbrace{{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + 1/2}\pars{k + 1}}}
> _{\ds{\color{#c00000}{=\half\bracks{\Psi\pars{1} - \Psi\pars{\half}} = \ln\pars{2}\ \mbox{when}\ n \to \infty}}}\
> +\ 
> \overbrace{\half\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k + 1} -\ln\pars{n}}}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\half\,\gamma\ \mbox{when}\ n \to \infty}}}\
> -\ \underbrace{{3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{n}}_{\ds{\color{#00f}{\Large ?}}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look up the Digamma function ($\Psi$)

Answer (score 1):

With $H_n$ denoting the $n$th harmonic number, your expression involves as main part $H_{2^n+1}-\frac12H_{2^{n-1}}$.
We know from Euler, that
$H_n=\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})$, hence
$$\begin{align}H_{2^n+1}-\frac12H_{2^{n-1}}&=H_{2^n}-\frac12H_{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{2^{n}+1}\\&=n\ln 2+\gamma +\frac1{2^{n}+1}+\frac1{2^{n+1}}-\frac12\left((n-1)\ln2+\gamma+\frac1{2^n}\right)+O(2^{-2n})\\
&=\frac {n+1}2\ln 2+\frac\gamma2+O(2^{-n})\end{align}$$
Thus if you replace "$-2\ln n$" with something "$-\frac12\ln 2^n$" in your expression, we obtain a limit value, $\frac{\ln2+\gamma}2$.

Comment: He originally had $\frac1n$ as the last term. I had no idea if he meant $\frac1{2n\pm1}$ or $\frac1{2\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+1}$. I certainly didn't expect him to change it to $\frac1{2^n+1}$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant to put $2n+1$ there, given the previous state of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Add the inverses of the even numbers to your series. You'll get a harmonic series, asymptotically equal to $\ln 2n + \gamma$.

Now check what you added. The sum of inverses of the even numbers is like half of a half-length harmonic series.